# Prove an identity for any $a, b \in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been trying to use the $|z|^2 = z\overline{z}$ to transform the identity and then just compare the sides but I end up having something inequal.
What's a good and efficient solution to this?

Identity to prove:

$$|1-\overline{a}b|+|a-b|^2 = (1+|ab|)^2 - (|a|^2 + |b|^2)$$

Comment: As you say, use $|z|^2=z\overline z$.

Comment: Don't you want $|1-\overline a b|^2-|a-b|^2=1+|ab|^2-(|a|^2+|\b^2|)?$

Comment: that's exactly what confused me. I think the identity should look like you've said because it's pretty easy to prove then, but in the book it's exactly like I wrote, with the parentheses to the power of 2.

Comment: Or you could have $\cdots=(1+|ab|)^2-(|a|+|b|)^2$.

Comment: The "identity" is obviously false. Just set $a=b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

After some answers/comments I've realized that the identity is wrongly written in the book. With a tiny edit in the text, it can be proven easily. Thanks for the help! (Answers given by: [Lord Shark The Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown) and [amsmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/487169/amsmath).